# Computing float to 2 digits only (not formatting/rounding off 6 digits after decimal to 2)

Tags: c, decimal, rounding, ieee-754, decimal-point

I am running a computation on an embedded processor which involves a float operation like this:

```
a = (float)23 / (float)3;  // a = 7.666....7
```

This is a long computation, and my app is OK with a certain amount of rounding error; I mean 7.67 or 7.66 doesn't matter.  Is there a way to cut down the amount of computation time spent in computing the float, or telling `math.h` to 2 digits ?

Any idea how to do this ?

PS: 
Now I know many will suggest using fixed point, but I have specific requirements.

Comment: You want a single division computation to run _faster?_

Comment: I have all things happening there. Not just a division, I have multiplications, additions as well.

Comment: no your code only has a division, from what you posted

Comment: I was just giving an example of the compute-time rounding I was looking for. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please supply these specific requirement, or we may end having an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here ;-)

Comment: Interesting thing, the XY problem: I am actually looking to reduce floating point computation time by computing less decimal places. Do you think it is do-able ?

Comment: Please supply the reasons of not using fixed-point. And what do you think about my answer?

Comment: You know how computing with 3-bit arithmetic is more expensive than computing with 32-bit arithmetic? Well it's the same with floating-point.

Answer (score 2):

Precision is determined by the data type, common types like float and double have a fixed precision that can't change, but there are libraries like [libfixmath](http://code.google.com/p/libfixmath/downloads/detail?name=libfixmath_r64.tar.gz&can=2&q=) that let you perform fast non-integer maths (in this case using `int32_t`)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can 'tell' `math.h` (in this regard); `float` does not have precision options.

If you want less computational intensive calculations you must use other types or methods.

You already mention the best candidate: fixed-point.  But, for obscure reasons, you say that you can't use it.

Other idea is to scale up your calculations by for example a factor 10,000, and keep everything as `int` (or `long`er).  Then, only scale down to `float` when needed.  But of course, it depends on your problem if you can do this.

Comment: Well, I would like to hear more people tell me their experiences :-)

Comment: @boffin Thanks! It may help to tell why you can't use fixed-point ;-)

Comment: There is a lot more info required to be shared, than I am allowed to... rules !! sorry :-(

Comment: @boffin Ah, known problem ;-)